# negative transition probabilities in the heston model

Tags: option-pricing, r, probability, american-options, heston

I've been trying to implement a bivariate tree for pricing american options with the heston model in R using the paper of Beliaeva and Nawalkha (http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1107934).

However I am obtaining negative transition probabilities for the middle node change of the stock price. I am pretty sure my coding is correct, I also cross-checked with the book by Rouah (http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118548256.html) and what I did resembles the code there.

Has anyone else experienced this or can give some pointers?

EDIT:
Here's my code for the stock probabilities. As a sample I used the numbers given in the Beliaeva paper: S_0 = 100, V_0 = 0.04, sigma = 0.1, kappa = 3, theta = 0.04, rho = -0.1.

The results I got where: (0.4860517840, -0.0008249158, 0.5147731319)

```
stockProb <- function(v0,vt,yt,sigma,kappa,rho,delT)
{
  muY <- (rho/sigma*kappa-0.5)*vt
  sigmayt <- sqrt(1-rho^2)*sqrt(vt)
  sigmay0 <- sqrt(1-rho^2)*sqrt(v0)
  if(vt > 0)
  {
    k <- ceiling(sqrt(vt/v0))
  }
  else
  {
    k <- 1
  }

  I <- round(muY/k/sigmay0*sqrt(delT))
  yu <- yt + (I+1)*k*sigmay0*sqrt(delT)
  ym <- yt + I*k*sigmay0*sqrt(delT)
  yd <- yt + (I-1)*k*sigmay0*sqrt(delT)  
  eu <- yu - yt - muY*delT
  em <- ym - yt - muY*delT
  ed <- yd - yt - muY*delT
  pu <- 0.5*(sigmayt^2*delT + em*ed)/k^2/sigmay0^2/delT
  pm <- -(sigmayt^2*delT + eu*ed)/k^2/sigmay0^2/delT
  pd <- 0.5*(sigmayt^2*delT +eu*em)/k^2/sigmay0^2/delT  
  ps <- c(pu,pm,pd)
  ps
}
```

Comment: Hi Season, welcome to Quant.SE! As the probabilities are negative I think it's best to show your code anyway. Without the code people will probably think it's a bug.

Comment: I can't really comment on the paper or the tree discretization in it, but trees seem like a pretty crazy way of solving the Heston PDE compared to implicit finite differences.

Comment: No luck yet for me. Can you the complete invocation of the function? Do you by any chance have `v0` and `vt` equal?

Comment: Well yes in the first step vt and v0 are equal but that is according to the paper.

Comment: BTW: thanks for sharing the paper. I'm still reading it. The authors spend quite some time on these negative probabilities and apparently a number of things can go wrong. I do wonder though: in the first step shouldn't `v0` be the volatility now and `vt` the vol at the next step.

Comment: You're welcome ;-) I think in the first step they should be equal since you want k(0), the node span for the different outcomes after time 0. Upon rereading the paper now for the xth time, theres a footnote somewhere at the end where they specify if the middle node is still negative one should adjust by k <- k+1 which now leaves me wondering if they do it just for the probabilities or in the calculation of the actual values in the nodes aswell..

Comment: I read the paper and looked at the code and could not find it either.  Nonetheless, three different things struck me as easily possible.  Please note for the future it would be better if you commented your code.  The first is a well known problem in computational algebra.  All computer calculations of the types quants use can be looked at as containing both a deterministic portion and a random portion because there is no easy translation from decimal to binary.  The simplest version of this is $1/3*3=.\bar{9}\ne{1}$.  (continued)

Comment: (continued) If your sample size is large enough, small discrepancies will always be present.  You used the round function.  The second is that these appear to be Frequentist estimates and one of the little known side effects is that you can get impossible answers from time to time as a side effect of the guarantee against false positives.  I teach future data analysts and I have a set of examples of preposterous results, such as proving that babies can float when they are born using only data.  (continued)

Comment: (continued) In Frequentism the confidence is in the procedure not the specific result or the data.  The data is conditioned on the model.  Third, and finally, there may be no bug, but your data may need cleaned.  Do you have any negative prices?  Are short sales properly accounted for?  Is anything reversed accidentally in the data?  Are there zeros where they do not belong?